# Play Framework Inject Error

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am trying to inject the JPAApi into my controller using Play 2.5 but I keep getting the following exception.

com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:39)
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:34)
  while locating play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider
  while locating play.db.jpa.JPAApi
    for parameter 0 at controllers.HomeController.<init>(HomeController.java:20)
  while locating controllers.HomeController
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:40)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

This is my controller.

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private JPAApi jpaApi;

    @Inject
    public HomeController(JPAApi jpaApi) {
        this.jpaApi = jpaApi;
    }

    public Result index() {
        jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select max(age) from people");
            return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
        });
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) you've got a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader` on the first line - is this dependency configured? 2) what does your Guice configuration look like?

Comment: The example I am following doesn't mention anything about needing to configure Guice, what file would it be in? I have a Module class that seems to be related to Guice

Comment: DOM4J is not found (or one of its dependencies) ... as the message says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just bumped into a bug in `sbt` (the build tool Play is using).
This bug arrises with Hibernate version 5.2.1 (but not with 5.2.0).

Hibernate 5.2.1 started do exclude all transitive dependencies of `dom4j` with a `maven` syntax that `sbt` can't handle yet.

The workaround for now is to add

```
"dom4j" % "dom4j" % "1.6.1" intransitive()
```

to your `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt` (in parallel to the Hibernate dependency).

For more detailed information have a look at the `sbt` bug itself which can be found here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1431

The Hibernate bug I reported (but has been closed as it turned out to be a `sbt` issue) can be found here:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10916

Comment: Man you rock ! Thanks.

Comment: sbt 0.13.13 fixed the bug, so this workaround isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: One more thing: If you upgraded sbt to 0.13.13 or higher you then also need to remove `dom4j` from your local ivy cache by removing `~/.ivy2/cache/dom4j` (or the whole``~/.ivy2/cache` or `~/.ivy2/` folder)

Answer (score 0):

based on the small snippet you've provided i'm running on the assumption that you're using the Play Java API. assuming as much, i'd first recommend you refer to the Play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection) on dependency injection.

if you've bootstrapped your project using one of the Activator templates, you probably ended up with the following two files (among many others):

```
.
├── app
│   ├── Module.java
└── conf
    └── application.conf
```

"Modules" are one way to configure bindings in Guice (basically what Guice will serve back when a component requests injection of a given type).

in the interest of getting you up and running in the meantime...

...first, in the `application.conf` file under the **play.modules** section, uncomment the line to add to the enabled set of modules, so you'll end up with something like this:

```
play.modules {
    enabled += Module
}
```

...next, assuming you have an interface named `JPAApi` with a concrete implementation `JPAApiImpl`... update the `Module.java` as follows:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(JPAApi.class).to(JPAApiImpl.class);
    }
}
```

(or if `JPAApi` is a concrete implementation itself, you could just bind that to itself)

restart your application and your controller should be injected.

Comment: Play does all Guice configuration by itself. JPAAPi binding is done by Play, it does not need to declare a module for this. Error does not come due to Guice not-configured(it should not). I think that the problem comes from db configuration.

Comment: @AlaSchneider - ah-ha, thanks for the feedback! so i guess wiring up your own modules is only necessary so far as customizing the bindings?